# ¿Como Usar El Método ProcessBuilder De Java?

Tags: java

He formulado esta pregunta con el fin de que pudieran ayudarme o explicarme mi duda que ha surgido por la necesidad de ejecutar comandos y este método ProcessBuilder es utilizado para ello. Aclarando el punto necesito ayuda porque no entiendo como utilizar esta clase. El código que recolecte es este:

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
 Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
 env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
 env.remove("OTHERVAR");
 env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
 pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
 Process p = pb.start();
```

Aquí surge el problema no entiendo como usar este código.

Obtuve este código de la pagina: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: Creo que deberías de ser más específico sobre lo que quieres realizar ya que simplemente hablas de la necesidad de ejecutar comandos.

Comment: ¿Qué parte no entiendes del código? ¿Qué es lo que te dificulta? ¿Qué necesitas lograr?

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es el papel de este fragmento por asi decirlo:

Comment: env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
 env.remove("OTHERVAR");
 env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
 pb.directory(new File("myDir"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diras la **clase ProcessBuilder**, y como bien lo dice su nombre, se encarga en crear procesos. Más específicamente, esta es usada para pasar parámetros a las aplicaciones:

```
// en linux
final String commands[] = {"ls", "/"}; // estos son los comandos a ejecutar, seria: 
                                      // usuario@usuario-pc:~$ ls /

Process process = new ProcessBuilder(commands).start(); // se crea el proceso
                                                       // usando los comandos


// ProcessBuilder.directory(new File("ruta")); donde ruta = la carpeta del ejecutable

// Se lee la salida
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}

// Esperamos que el proceso termine
try {
  int exitValue = process.waitFor();
  System.out.println("\nCódigo de salida: "+ exitValue);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

[Documentación de la clase ProcessBuilder - docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: Amigo ocurre un error no me ejecuta un comando que es el ln -s, si podrías ayudarme gracias

Comment: ls es un comando de LINUX, por lo tanto no funciona en otros sistemas operativos: En windows: final String commands[] = {"cmd", "/C", "dir"};

Comment: Pero no hay un comando de android que cumpla la función de crear un enlace simbólico, porque en mi incansable busque he probado con muchos como ln -sv y ln -sf, hasta incluso este que encontré en una pregunta ln [-fhinsv] (la pregunta es esta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222347/android-system-link-failing-function-on-implemented). Gracias

Comment: Estamos en la pregunta: ¿Como Usar El Método ProcessBuilder De Java?, puedes abrir otra pregunta con la nueva.

Comment: Ok gracias, seguiré el concejo.